# Error:(44, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.nukc.loadmorelayout:library:0.1.0

Tags: android, maven

[http://search.maven.org/](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.nukc.loadmorelayout%7Clibrary%7C0.1.0%7Caar)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14j1T.png)

I am getting the above error while importing the library from compiler

```
com.github.nukc.loadmorelayout:library:0.1.0
Error:(44, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.nukc.loadmorelayout:library:0.1.0
```

My build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "2.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'

    compile 'com.github.nukc.loadmorelayout:library:0.1.0'
}
```

Comment: did you check my answer

Comment: yes, i checked. i created a new  repositories and upload the library to add the jcenter, now, can compile successfully. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I have a question to you .

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can i publish my own library ??

Comment: [how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en), This article can help you

Comment: Okay .Thanks .Checking

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead of yours.

```
compile 'com.nukc.loadmorelayout:library:0.1'
```

Comment: I'm sorry. 'com.nukc.loadmorelayout:library:0.1' is wrong. Because the library is my, my own mistake. But I don't know where it went wrong.